# Infinite ListView scroll animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-listview

I have an "infinite" ListView like

```
ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final i = index % items.length;
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("index: $i ${items[i]}"),
    );
  },
);
```

That show continuosuly elements inside "items" list.
Now i need to avoid manual scrolling and add an animation that smoothly scroll indefinitely that list.
How can i do?

Comment: you can use scroll controller for that.

Comment: with scrollController.animateTo() i can't set infinite animation duration, because it requires a specific duration.

Answer (score 1):

you can use scroll controller for that.

according to doc https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollController/animateTo.html animteTo() is future so you can make a recursive function and call it continuously.

```
function(){
scrollcontroller.animateTo().then((value){
Future.delay((duration),()=>function()) //here delay is for some smooth ness
});
}
```

this is unoptimized so you have to optimize it to visual, i mean how much you have to sroll i don't know so.